# Java - Shuffling Elements and Outputting Specific Amounts

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, shuffle, element

In Java, I was just told to use this structure for shuffling a list of items:

```
List<String> tasks = Arrays.asList("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8");
Collections.shuffle(tasks);
for(String task : tasks){
    System.out.println(task); 
}
```

The problem with this solution for my program is I only want to randomly output a number of elements as chosen by the user (meaning, if the user wants only five elements instead of all eight, I want only five of the elements randomly outputted). I've never actually used a lambda or that form of forloop before (I'm completely new to Java). I know how to use arrays, and I tried finding a shuffle option for arrays but came up with nothing. I also tried this:

```
int num = console.nextInt();
List<String> tasks = Arrays.asList("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8");
Collections.shuffle(tasks);
for(int i = 1; i <= num; i++){
    String task = tasks;
    System.out.println(task); 
}
```

But obviously, this format is very, very incorrect (mainly because, again, I don't know how that format works). How can I get the list shuffled AND output ONLY the amount of elements the user wants?

Note: I do NOT have Java 8.

Comment: Check `Random` class

Comment: I think you're looking for the `List` `get(int index)` method which can be used to get the element at a specific index from the list. eg: `String task = tasks.get(i)`.

Comment: `for(String task : tasks.subList(0,5){`

Comment: you want to first n elements or to be shuffled or want to get n elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tasks` is a `List`, which can't be assigned to a `String`. You need to get a specific `String` from `tasks` to assign to `task` - or you could just do away with `task` altogether because it isn't necessary to declare a separate variable for it. Your `for` loop should look like this:

```
for (int i=0; i<num; i++) {
    System.out.println(tasks.get(i));
}
```

Note that I also changed `int i=1; i<=num;` from your code to `int i=0; i<num;`. Indices begin at 0, so it's generally good practice to begin your loop at 0, as you'll be calling `tasks.get(0)`, `tasks.get(1)`, and so on.

Comment: Your example works perfectly! I do usually start with zero in for loops when working with arrays, but this time I didn't because I thought I'd just be dealing with num, and I'd end up putting "i <= (num-1)", and I didn't want to complicate things where it wasn't necessary. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 4):

Would there be anything wrong with shuffling the initial 8 elements (randomly), and then simply returning a subset of that list?  Consider the following code:

```
public class ListTest {
    public static List<String> getRandomItems(int num) {
        List<String> tasks = Arrays.asList("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8");
        Collections.shuffle(tasks);

        return tasks.subList(0, num);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // take 5 random elements
        List<String> randomList = getRandomItems(5);
        for (String item : randomList) {
            System.out.println("Found an item: " + item);
        }
    }
}
```

Note that it should not matter *which* subset of the original 8 elements you take since they will be in a random order.  Rather, the only thing which should matter is that you choose the correctly-sized subset.

Comment: What does "subset" mean in this context? Does the "return tasks.subList(0, num);" print out the rearranged list elements from 0 to num? The example isn't compiling when I copy/pasted it in (it says it's missing semicolons).

Comment: @Ray25Lee I added a sample program which you can run directly.  I don't believe there are any syntax problems.

Answer (score 0):

After shuffling the list, you can get elements from the head via `Iterator`.

```
int num = console.nextInt();
List<String> tasks = Arrays.asList("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8");
Collections.shuffle(tasks);
java.util.Iterator<String> taskItr = tasks.iterator();
for(int i = 1; i <= num && taskItr.hasNext(); i++){
    String task = taskItr.next();
    System.out.println(task); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After the shuffle ask the user how many elements does he need... then use `List.sublist` from 0 to the given number

## Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    List<String> tasks = Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8");
    Collections.shuffle(tasks);
    System.out.println("how many do you need??");
    int userAnswer = sc.nextInt();
    List<String> res = tasks.subList(0, userAnswer);
    System.out.println("here are " + res);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to skin the cat

```
int num = console.nextInt();
for(String task : tasks){
    System.out.println(task); 

    if (num--) <= 0) break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your second code example wouldn't even compile because you cannot assing a `List<String>` to a `String`. You'd have to use `String task = tasks.get(i);`

If you want to output random elements from the list you can just use `Random`to get a random number in the range 0 to `list.size()` and output the element at the corresponding position:

```
List<String> tasks = Arrays.asList("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8");
Collections.shuffle(tasks);
int num = 5;
Random random = new Random();

for(int i = 0; i < num; i++){
    System.out.println(tasks.get(random.nextInt(tasks.size())));
}
```

The problem here is that you might output the same element multiple times because of the (pseudo-)randomly generated number. A way to fix this problem is to use a Set, which does not allow duplicates, and fill it until you have enough unique elements from your list:

```
List<String> tasks = Arrays.asList("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8");
Collections.shuffle(tasks);
int num = 5;
Random random = new Random();
Set<String> selectedTasks = new HashSet<String>();

do {
    selectedTasks.add(tasks.get(random.nextInt(tasks.size())));
} while (selectedTasks.size() < num);

System.out.println(selectedTasks);
```